# Devise validate email property with exclusion of words and @myapp.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

Trying to validate the email field in a rails devise app with a word exclusion.

```
  validates :email, :exclusion => {:in => ["admin", "root",,
                                   :message => "is reserved"}
```

Wich works great on the :username field but not on the email.

I suspect that Devise is "taken over" the validation of the email field and I need to super/ overrule the registrations controller of Devise.

How could I:

- Prevent emails with words based on an :exclusion
- Prevent emails with @myapp.com so users don't use the domain the app runs on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write [custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) to achieve what you want. Example from the guide:

> The easiest way to add custom validators for validating individual
>   attributes is with the convenient ActiveModel::EachValidator. In this
>   case, the custom validator class must implement a validate_each method
>   which takes three arguments: record, attribute and value which
>   correspond to the instance, the attribute to be validated and the
>   value of the attribute in the passed instance.

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
end
```

Comment: I finally used a def method for this inside my model and a validate :my_method to get it fixed thanks for pointing out above should come in handy soon

Answer (score 0):

After checking if it is an e-mail, I would split the two validations. One for exclusion, and other for domain. You can retrieve the current domain when using passenger.

```
validate :email_username_is_not_on_blacklist, :email_domain_is_allowed

EXCLUDED_USERNAMES = "admin", "root"
EXCLUDED_DOMAINS = "myapp.com"

def email_username_is_not_on_blacklist
  user, domain = email.split("@")
  errors.add(:email, "E-mail user is not allowed") if self.class.EXCLUDED_USERNAMES.include?(user)
end

def email_domain_is_allowed
  user, domain = email.split("@")
  errors.add(:email, "E-mail domain is not allowed") if self.class.EXCLUDED_DOMAINS.include?(domain)
end
```